# Datatables html sort with data containing unordered lists

Tags: sorting, datatables

Can anyone help me with a sorting problem I have DataTables.  I need to sort the first column of my table in descending order.  The column contains some cells with unordered lists.  What I would like is that it sorts the cells with unordered lists using the contents of the first list item.  I'm using columnDefs type html, but this is not enough to resolve this problem.  The sort systematically sorts the cells with the unordered lists at the bottom of the table, instead of in the logical sequence.

I've set up a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet2/ka59nb5q/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
"order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
"columnDefs": [
        {"type": "html", "targets": [ 0 ] },
        {"width": "50%", "targets": [ 0, 1 ] }
        ]    
}    
);} );
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the sorting with custom function to do that, like this:

```
// register custom sorting function
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-list'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        // if there is ul>li we get the value of first
        var $first_li = $('ul li:first', td);
        if($first_li.length > 0) {
            return $first_li.text();
        }
        // there is no ul>li in td we get its value
        return $(td).text();
    } );
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "columns": [
                { "orderDataType": "dom-list" },// set order type to custom function
                null
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {"width": "50%", "targets": [ 0, 1 ] }
            ]
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: My only improvement is that I moved the orderDataType into the ColumnDefs
"columnDefs": [
    {"orderDataType": "dom-list", "targets": 0 },
    {"width": "50%", "targets": [ 0, 1 ] }
   ]